# TealScript - Budget increase

Tags: algorand, tealscript

is there some recomended way how to increase the tealscript opcode budget?

I see some older documentation here: https://developer.algorand.org/tutorials/understanding-teal-opcode-budget/

PyTeal has OpUp call - https://pyteal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/opup.html#ensure-budget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `increaseOpcodeBudget()`. This will create/delete an app for more opcode budget. More sophisticated methods are possible in the future, but this AVM PR might change the need for that: https://github.com/algorand/go-algorand/pull/5943

TEALScript docs: https://tealscript.netlify.app/api/functions/increaseopcodebudget/#_top